# Перенос текста на другую строку или его вертикальная ориентация

Tags: java, swing, intellij-idea, gui

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Добавил текст на панель. Как сделать **перенос** слов на другую строку, а еще лучше - как написать текст **вертикально**?

Свойства вот:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения] [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

В `property`-ях не нашел такой функции... В интернете тоже вроде нет.

Answer (score 0):

Как писать вертикально не знаю а для переноса надо делать во так скажем у нас такой текст `я иду иду` (тут нам надо перенос пишем `<br>`) `<br>` и еще `иду`

Comment: @Mr Klonwar не за что )))

Comment: Не, не работает. Там  нельзя <br> поставить..

Comment: можешь код скинуть?

Comment: Попробуйте `\n`.

Comment: Там такая штука, сам код не редактируется (Может это я кривой), только визуально работать

Comment: понимаю вашу проблему но как вы не можете редактировать код я не понимаю ((